# Div not visible if position: relative

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a `container` class. The div is called panel:

```
.panel {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(img/launch1.png);
    height: 80%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The container:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Whenever I change the `.panel`'s position to relative, it just disappears and is no longer visible. It's still in the site itself but it places itself somewhere outside of the monitor. Not sure what's wrong here. Any fresh eyes that can help me out?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle to demo ur issue?

Comment: @AhsN I solved it, I overlooked a tiny part xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to set a height for the `.container`.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Otherwise, you need to set a value in pixel for the `.panel` height, and not a percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, the `container` needed a `height: 100%`!